# Get All Domain users in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to get the list of all the users for the domain on a GAE app (using python). When I hit this URL https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/user/2.0 . I get an authorization error. How can I authenticate for this GET hit.

Comment: why do you want do do that? are you some sort of spammer or something?

Comment: I dont want to get All the Google Accounts. But just the current domain account so that I can get all the organization members list on apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Provisioning API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_developers_protocol.html), and you'll need to authenticate via [OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html) first

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer from Chris, prepare for a bit of pain around authentication.  You have four options for read-only access, and one if you need read/write:

Marketplace authorization: if your app is on the Google Marketplace and a domain admin added you to the domain, you can use your app's Google Marketplace keys to access the provisioning API in read-only mode.

Domain OAuth: if you can get the domain admin to make a configuration change for you, your app can use the domain-wide OAuth keys for read-only access.

3-legged OAuth: if you are dealing with a superadmin user, you can request that they grant you temporary right to access the API in read-only mode.

Programmatic Login: lastly, you can ask them to give you an admin account username and password to login into the provisioning API.  This is the only mechanism that will give you the ability to change anything.

Comment: Thanks Jan Z for your detailed answer. Actually I am developing the app for my own organization so I have the admin access but the app is not added to marketplace. So can you tell me that what is the best option for me.

Comment: 2-Legged Oauth using domain keys.  It's the most stable one and does not rely in individual user accounts and privileges.  
Unfortunately setting this up is more painful than it needs to be at the moment - you need to enable domain OAuth (in Google Apps Console), then manually add the user feed to your own domain ("Manage third party OAuth Client Access").  You will **not** see anything confirming you did this, your code will just start working!
  
It's a bit daft that you have to do this, and it's not well documented, but there you go.